# Swift if #available not working as expected?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a shared framework that runs in both iOS and MacOS, and I've run into a situation where in MacOS Catalina I need to make an extra check. I thought that by using the swift #available this would work:

```
    if #available(OSX 10.15, *){
       /// My Catalina Code
     }
```

The truth is that this code passes in iOS. Would this be a bug, or is it not expected to be used this way ?

Comment: Try with macOS insted of OSX. Check the Apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html

Comment: @PolVilarrasa that was the answer. Can you add the answer so I can mark it as correct ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look through [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html) it should be like that.

```
if #available(macOS 10.15, *){
       /// My Catalina Code
     }
```

Comment: Wow - that was a time bomb that had been hidden in my code for three years. The original way was to use MACOS. That would have been great if Apple would have made that a warning when it encountered MACOS after they changed it.

Answer (score 2):

it should look like this:

```
    if #available(macCatalyst 10.15, *) {
        // use 10.15
    } else {

    }
```

if your using Catalyst.

other than that there is nothing that shows why your code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: runs in both iOS and MacOS

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use conditional compiling together with `#available`:

```
        #if os(macOS)
        if #available(macOS 15.0, *) {
            //...
        }
        #endif
```

Or an ugly workaround:

```
        if #available(macOS 15.0, iOS 9999.99, *) {
            //...
        }
```